# Having some trouble trying to assert multiple elements with toBeVisible() assertion

Tags: typescript, playwright

I've noticed `toBeVisible()` is failing when it detects multiple elements when running a test in debug mode. I've also noticed `toBeVisible` without the parenthesis passes when it detects multiple elements in an assertion.

I was wondering if there was anyway to get toBeVisible() with the parenthesis to pass when multiple elements are detected because I need to pass in the timeout argument below for this specific case, because the element Im waiting for is a rendering of the pages for an uploaded document which can take anywhere from 2 seconds to 2 min to display

the following line fails due to the locator being attached to multiple pages

```
await expect(locator).toBeVisible({ timeout: 10000 })
```

what I currently did was change the value of the global expect timeout in the config file so

```
await expect(locator).toBeVisible;
```

works, but I was wondering if there was anyway to avoid setting such a high timeout globally and just use the way set in the documentation but for cases with multiple elements.

Comment: I'm not sure what causes it but you can use `test.setTimeout(10000);` at the start of your test as a workaround. Take a look at https://playwright.dev/docs/test-timeouts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To assert multiple elements you can do:

```
await expect(locator).toHaveCount(42);
```

To make a locator more specific you can reduce it to:

```
await expect(locator).nth(42).toBeVisible();
```

Which selects the 42th element. Or just change it to `0`.

The reason why it passes without parenthesis is because it never gets called, then you can also just remove it. :)

Comment: Interesting, Im shocked I didnt get a syntax error or some other exception with writing `toBeVisible` and that we just dont call it. Im coming from selenium(c#) and we have a prop like `.Displayed` so i assumed it was working similar to that. 
Also whenever the debugger runs it looks like it waits for those specific elements with `toBeVisible` so i figured it was just working.

Also Im trying to avoid setting a hard coded number because the page numbers can change with each test execution, youre saying using `nth(0)` would that just check for the first element it finds?

Comment: Thank you though Max! Appreciate this tool you guys have created.